# Prove that $x^2> \frac1e-1 $ and $e \gt 0$ $\implies x\lt -\sqrt{\lvert \frac 1e-1\rvert} $ or $ x\gt \sqrt{\lvert \frac 1e-1\rvert} $

Tags: calculus, inequality

[image]

$x^2> \frac1e-1 $ and $e \gt 0$ $\implies x\lt -\sqrt{\lvert \frac 1e-1\rvert} $ or $    x\gt \sqrt{\lvert \frac 1e-1\rvert} $

In my text book I have come across this implication. I am not able to justify its validity. In my opinion It should be as below

Given : $x^2> \frac1e-1 $ and $e \gt 0$

Case 1: $(\frac 1e-1) \gt0$ then $x^2> \frac1e-1 \implies \lvert x\rvert^{2} \gt$ $(\sqrt{\lvert \frac 1e-1\rvert})^2 \implies \lvert x\rvert \gt (\sqrt{\lvert \frac 1e-1\rvert})$

Case 2: $(\frac 1e-1) \lt0$ then $x^2> \frac1e-1 \implies  -x^2\lt -(\frac1e-1) \implies -x^2\lt \lvert \frac 1e-1\rvert$

I am not able to reach the given implication.

Any help towards this will be appreciated.

Comment: You probably mean $0 < e \leq 1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this statement is false: Take for example $e=4/3$, so the statement is
$$
x^2>-\frac{1}{4}\ \Rightarrow\ x<-\frac{1}{2}\ \text{or}\ x>\frac{1}{2}
$$
$x=0$, for instance, is a counterexample.

**Regarding the reference:** The proof is not quite accurate. Given $\epsilon>0$ you need to prove that there is $K$ such that if
$x<K$, then $|\frac{1}{1+x^2}-0|<\epsilon$, that is
$$
x<K\Rightarrow \frac{1}{1+x^2}<\epsilon.
$$
It should be separated into two cases: if $1<\epsilon$, then you may take $K=0$, since $\frac{1}{1+x^2}\leq 1<\epsilon$ for every $x$. If $0<\epsilon\leq 1$, then as indicate in the reference, you may take $K=-\sqrt{\frac{1}{e}-1}$.

Comment: Yes your counterexample is enough to disprove it. I have added a reference to the statement. Can you please have a look at it and guide me if I am missing some point here.

Comment: See my additional comments @Rajkumar Kumawat.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment. But according to the definition as given in the reference above K is required to be positive. So we can't have $K=0$ right? Also it looks like we can have $K=e$ for the case $ e \gt 1$

Comment: Actually, it does not matter.  You may equivalently, say that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=L$ iff for every $\epsilon$ , there exist a $K$ (positive or negative) such that $x<K$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. If  the choice $K=0$ is still bother you, take any other $K$. It will be still true since $\frac{1}{1+x^2}<\epsilon$, as I indicated, is true for all $x$, regardless the condition $x<K$.